# How to turn nested jQuery Promises into flat code structure using .done() and .then()

Tags: jquery, promise, es6-promise, uploadcare

Below's code using jQuery promises in combination with callbacks does the following:

1. Saves Group UUID to server using `storeGroupOnServer()`
2. Creates a DOM element for the group using `createGroupDomNode()`
3. Creates child elements for each image, using `createNewChildDomNode()`

How can this be written more flat (avoiding the nesting), using `.then()`?

```
groupPromise.done(function(fileGroupInfo) {
    storeGroupOnServer(fileGroupInfo.uuid, function(groupid){

        createGroupDomNode(groupid, function(groupnode){

            $.each(arrayOfFiles, function(i, file) {
                file.done(function(fileInfo) {
                    createNewChildDomNode(fileInfo.cdnUrl, groupnode);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Step 1: storeGroupOnServer():**

```
storeGroupOnServer = function(uuid, callback) {
    $.post('saveGroup.php', {uuid:uuid},
    function(data) {
        callback(data.groupid);
    },'json');
};
```

**Step 2: createGroupDomNode():**

```
createGroupDomNode = function(groupid, callback) {
    var cloner = $('#cloner');
    var newnode = cloner.clone(true);
    newnode.attr('id',groupid);
    newnode.removeClass('hide');
    cloner.after(newnode);
    callback(newnode);
}
```

**Step 3: createNewChildDomNode():**

```
function createNewChildDomNode(imgpath, groupdom){
    imgnode = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgpath);
    picnode = $('<picture/>').append(imgnode);
    $(groupdom).first().prepend(picnode);
}
```

Comment: Does the code work as it is?  Can you show a working example?  Are you asking how to change it up to make it "better".  If so this question is off topic for Stack Overlow and is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you can use `async`/`await` syntax if your target environments support it. it uses Promises behind the scenes but lets you write your functions in a synchronous-style syntax

Comment: @Taplar Yes, the code works, but it's part of Uploadcare. Sharing the whole code is a bit cumbersome. Yes, this is asking to improve this code. Thanks for the suggestion about Codereview.

Comment: Make `storeGroupOnServer` return the promise that `$.post` already creates. Do not take a callback.

Comment: `createGroupDomNode` seems to be entirely synchronous. It should not take a callback (nor create a promise) at all.

Comment: @Bergi `createNewChildDomNode()` needs to wait for `createGroupDomNode()` to be completed, how else would you do that?

Comment: What is in there that would "get completed"? You should be able to simply write `const 
groupnode = createGroupDomNode(groupid); … createNewChildDomNode(fileInfo.cdnUrl, groupnode);`

Answer (score 0):

Will give the start without having to rewrite the whole thing and let you fill in the rest

```
groupPromise.then(function(fileGroupInfo){
   return fileGroupInfo.uuid;
})
.then(storeGroupOnServer)
.then(createGroupDomNode)....



// uuid argument comes from return in groupPromise.then()
storeGroupOnServer = function(uuid) {
  // return the ajax promise
  return $.post('saveGroup.php', {uuid: uuid}, null, 'json')
        .then(function(data) {
           // return to next then() in chain which calls createGroupDomNode()
            return data.groupid;
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of start I was looking for. Appreciated.